# Centering left-aligned text over image

Tags: html, css

I want text over an image that's always centered. The following code achieves that. However, I have a further requirement in that I'd like the text itself to be left-aligned, as opposed to centered, and I'd like to specify a width of 100px for the text so that the words wrap. How can I achieve this?

```
<div id="typewritter-text">
    <span id='typewritter'>Lorem Ipsum</span>
</div>

#typewritter-text {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -65px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    top: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Try setting `text-align: left;` instead of `text-align: center;` and `width: 100px;` instead of `width: 100%;`.  If this works, I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fiddle to demonstrate the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ar14/gg076ew0/1/

```
#typewritter-text {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This is the CSS that you want. Make sure the parent container has position relative on it as well because you want it to be absolutely positioned relative to the parent not the whole page.

Comment: This doesn't work because it isn't overlapping the image, since the position of the parent here is relative.

Comment: Try defining a z-index if you want it to overlap: `z-index: 1`

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `text-align:center;` in your CSS, which sets the text to center-aligned.  Try changing this to `text-align: left;`.

To set the maximum width of the text area to 100 pixels, you should probably be doing `width: 100px;` instead of `width:100%;`.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that it doesn't center the span itself, although the text is centered...

Comment: OK, maybe you could try setting `left: 0px;` too.